# how to get an array of of the digits of an int in java

Tags: java, arrays

So this probably would be easy if done like this

```
public static [] nums(int j)
{
    int num = 12345;
    int[]thenums = [5];

    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
       thenums[4-i] = num%10;
       num = num/10;
    }

return the nums
}
```

i get {1,2,3,4,5}

but for some reason if the number starts with a 0 then it does not work
how to make this work if the number were

```
int num = 02141;
```

thanks

Comment: zero before a number? won't num just have 2141?

Comment: @Murali: It will have 2141 in octal.

Comment: @Jeremiah: true only if there was a backslash at the beginning no?

Comment: @Murali: Not according to http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html; they show octal constants using just the C syntax (0 on the front).

Comment: @Murali - no.  Read http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#3.10.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: Doh... I'd completely forgotten about octal literals. That explains why the value is showing up differently. (`02141` is treated as an octal literal; it's not the same value as `2141`.)

However, it sounds like the OP wants to "remember" the number of leading zeroes in a number. There's no way of doing that as an integer, because it's just remembering a value. What's the difference between seeing "3" birds and seeing "0000003" birds?

If you have a number representation where the leading zeroes are important, you're not just talking about an integer quantity, which is all that an `int` represents.

Where are you getting your input from? It sounds like you should just be maintaining it as a string from the start.

If you *always* want 5 digits, that's easy to do - and your current code should do it (when amended to actually compile) - something like this:

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int[] digits = getDigits(123);
        for (int digit : digits)
        {
            System.out.print(digit); // Prints 00123
        }
    }

    public static int[] getDigits(int value)
    {
        int[] ret = new int[5];
        for (int i = 4; i >=0 ; i--)
        {
            ret[i] = value % 10;
            value = value / 10;
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Now that's hard-coded to return 5 digits. If you don't know the number of digits at compile-time, but you *will* know it at execution time, you could pass it into the method:

```
public static int[] getDigits(int value, int size)
{
    int[] ret = new int[size];
    for (int i = size - 1; i >=0 ; i--)
    {
        ret[i] = value % 10;
        value = value / 10;
    }
    // Perhaps throw an exception here if value is not 0? That would indicate
    // we haven't captured the complete number

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: i dont think that was the question

Comment: actually, they are not.  The first one is a decimal literal, and second one is an octal literal.

Comment: though "who am I to suggest to Jon" feeling is there in my mind, leaving original answer around when you make edits will keep the comments posted below the answer relevant.

Comment: @Murali: I've added a *bit* more context, but I think it's more important for the answer itself to be clear to the reader than the comments. There's always the edit history if necessary.

Answer (score 3):

What happens in your code is that `02141` is not the same as `2141`; the first is octal (equivalent to `1121` decimal), while the second is `2141` decimal.

The relevant part of the Java Language Specification is [JLS 3.10.1](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#3.10.1), specifically the grammar productions for `DecimalNumeral` and `OctalNumeral`.

Comment: @Julio: remove any `0`'s from the front of the number.  `int num = 2141;` will not have the problem.

Comment: @Jeremiah: the 0 is an integral part of the array that I want to create though

Comment: @Julio: You just need to remove it in your source code; you can still put it into the array (as long as you do not try to use the array as an integer literal later).

Comment: @Jeremiah: mmm, I am newbie still could you please expand a little on this.

Comment: @Jeremiah: also the number may not always have a 0 at the first digit

Comment: @Julio: See my amended answer.

Comment: @Julio: Just change the `02141` in your source code to `2141`, and the array should still have `02141` on output like you want.